# How to sort string based on substring with C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string

```
string myStr = "*20@Apple#*10@Banana#*-5@Orange#*8@Cherries#";
```

I want an array that contains only fruit names from this string, but it should be sorted based on a value that is associated with it.

For example, in this string

```
Apple => 20
Banana => 10
Orange => -5
Cherries => 8
```

I want this this array as a result

> Orange, cherries, Banana, Apple

Thank You!

Comment: Split, split, sort

Comment: 1. Extract the data into a structure that you can work with more easily (i.e. a list of fruits and their values) 2. Sort the list based on the values. 3. Select the fruits from the now-ordered list and return as `string` array.

Comment: Also: why are apple, banana, and orange all singular but cherries is plural?

Comment: Any reason why you unsmected thr answer

Answer (score 5):

```
var input = "*20@Apple#*10@Banana#*-5@Orange#*8@Cherries#";

var result = input
      .Split(new []{'#','*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(x => x.Split('@'))
      .Select(x => (Rank : int.Parse(x[0]), Value : x[1]))
      .OrderBy(x => x.Rank)
      .Select(x => x.Value)
      .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",result));
```

**Output**

```
Orange, Cherries, Banana, Apple
```